# How to check three state (null, false, true) value?

Tags: php, isset

I have such a piece of code:

```
public function setValue($flag) {
  $this->value = isset($flag) ? (bool) $flag : null;
}
```

I assume, that $flag can denote either null, or false, or true. (The reason I do typecasting is that I just care about types.)

EDIT:
This is my goal:

- if $flag is null, then $this->value is null,
- if (bool)$flag is false, then $this->value is false,
- if (bool)$flag is true, then $this->value is true.

This is what my code says. And I'm wondering, is the code I submitted a good way to achieve my goal, or is there maybe a better (simpler, more elegant) one?

Comment: Why would `$flags` not be set?

Comment: It makes more sense to check if $flag is set BEFORE it's used as a parameter into the function, not afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

I just read your edit, and if your code is working then keep doing it the way you're already doing it as that way is convenient and neat. The only thing is that I would check for `isset` first.

```
$this->value = null;
if(isset($flag)) {
    setValue($flag);
}

public function setValue($flag) {
  $this->value = (bool) $flag
}
```

Comment: You should flesh up your answer a bit.

Comment: @Evan, I agree with you. But you should notice, that your code does exactly the same thing my code does -- but my one is shorter;) Typecasting $flag to bool is equal to empty($flag), isn't it?

Comment: I don't have any problem;) I'm simply wondering if I could write my code better? Or is there maybe any native php way to achieve my goal?

Comment: @jacek.ciach Other than checking for `isset` separately, no I don't think you should change it.

Comment: @Evan, you said that you would check for `isset` first -- doesn't my code check for `isset` first, either? hmm...

Comment: @jacek.ciach I mean PRIOR to sending it to the function :)

Comment: @jacek.ciach I've done one final update with an example of how you should check for isset.

Comment: @Evan, Oh, I have to consider that. Thanks a lot:)

Answer (score 0):

The `isset` will return `false` if the value is `NULL`. You should also check by `is_null`

Comment: I know it will. And then $this->value is null. So it works as I want.